# JavaPoet adding a list of enum constants

Tags: java, javapoet

Is there a way to add a dynamic list of EnumConstants - I would expect to see `addEnumConstants()`.

There seems to be no parallel to `addFields()` or `addMethods()`?

Comment: can you give an example plz

Comment: I have a List (as in ArrayList) of constants that need to be added to an enum.  How do I do that when I don't know those values in advance.

Comment: what to do you mean by added to an enum? Some code would definitely help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed [no methods](https://square.github.io/javapoet/javadoc/javapoet/com/squareup/javapoet/TypeSpec.Builder.html) to add a list of enum constants. Quoting from the [documentation](https://github.com/square/javapoet#enums):

> Use `enumBuilder` to create the enum type, and `addEnumConstant()` for each value:

In this case, you will need to loop over all of your enum values and add them one by one by calling [`addEnumConstant()`](https://square.github.io/javapoet/javadoc/javapoet/com/squareup/javapoet/TypeSpec.Builder.html#addEnumConstant%28java.lang.String%29) on the builder instance.

Sample code that adds all the enum frol the `List<String> myEnumList` :

```
TypeSpec.Builder builder = TypeSpec.enumBuilder("Roshambo").addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
for (String str : myEnumList) {
    builder.addEnumConstant(str);
}
TypeSpec typeSpec = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet#enums) for adding enum constants. You can start creating a TypeSpec.Builder and call .addEnumConstant in a loop from a list of values.

However, if you do not have your enum constants list prior to generating the enum type, you cannot generate them dynamically. Enums constants have to be a constant list in an enum class. An alternative is to generate a singleton class with a dynamic list of valid values and a .get static function that replaces an enum's .valueOf function.